# ServiceStack ORMLite Fluent Configuration

Tags: database, servicestack, fluent, ormlite-servicestack

I am looking to create a new project using ServiceStacks OrmLite. I have used EntityFramework in the past and I prefer the use of the fluent api for mapping over the invasive attributes.

Does OrmLite have an equivalent api or am I forced to use the attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, Fluent Configuration isn't supported in [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/) just attributed model-first POCOs.

It's something we're looking at doing, but wont be available for a while.

Comment: Hi Mythz, what if I need my POCO classes to be put in a portable class library so that they can be shared by SL, WP clients? I guess the attributes/tags are not PCLable, are they?